# How do I convert a string into a vector of command line arguments?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

In python, how do a parse a string in the same way that the command line argument string is parsed in order to construct `sys.argv`?

I'd like to do the following

First: allow for passing in an optional argument vector to `main` in my `runnable.py`:

```
def main(argv=[]):
    argv = argv or sys.argv[1:]
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
    ... more parser config ...
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

Then, in another module I'd like to be able to use this main function from within python:

```
argv = how_do_i_do_this('''-f text.txt -o -q "Multi word argument" arg2 "etc."''')
assert(argv == ['-f', 'text.txt', '-o', '-q', 'Multi word argument', 'arg2', 'etc.'])
runnable.main(argv)
```

Comment: Where are you getting such a string from in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('''-f text.txt -o -q "Multi word argument" arg2 "etc."''')
['-f', 'text.txt', '-o', '-q', 'Multi word argument', 'arg2', 'etc.']
```

Also, [Python mutable defaults are the source of all evil](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/08/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil/). Don't use `argv=[]` as the default argument for `main`, use `argv=None` and then check its type inside the body of `main`:

```
def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv[1:]

# ...
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was about to post something using `getopt` but your solution is far better.

Comment: I used `argv=[]` to indicate that the flavor of the argument is a list (I use `''` when the expected a string, `{}` when the expected value is a dict, and so on).  Makes sense to me.  Saying "don't mutate arguments with default values" is as good a rule of thumb as "don't use mutable default arguments".

Comment: Did you read my link? You could run into some nasty bugs by using default arguments that are mutable, especially if you want to call the same function multiple times, because the same reference to the mutable object is used for each call. Default arguments are not there to be used as an indicator of what data type a function expects - use type hints and docstrings for that.

Comment: Yes I read it.  I'm aware of python's behavior wrt default arguments. I don't find the reasoning convincing.  To me, unless the purpose of the function is specifically to change the value of an argument, then a function should not mutate the values passed to it.  The, admittedly artificial, example in the article does exactly that.   Keeping that as the rule also avoids problems; e.g. the the implementation of `x=['hi',]; y = compute_patterns(x)` in the article *changes the value of x* even if you handle the default argument in the manner suggested.