# Python how to set variable in quotation marks

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a small script in python to get metadata from my mp4 files using ffprobe. The problem is that I need to pass the filename in quotation marks, see:

```
ffprobe -print_format json -show_streams -show_format -loglevel quiet -hide_banner /home/mike/Desktop/2 Stars at Night.mp4
```

Current situation:

```
import subprocess


def scrape(file):
    scrape_cmd = ('ffprobe -print_format json -show_streams -show_format -loglevel quiet -hide_banner '
                  f'{file}')
    result = subprocess.run(scrape_cmd.split(), capture_output=True)
    print(result)


scrape(file="'/home/mike/Desktop/2 Stars at Night.mp4'")
```

How can I properly pass the filename to the function? as its currently returning:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['ffprobe', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_streams', '-show_format', '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-hide_banner', "'/home/claris/Desktop/2", 'Stars', 'at', 'Night.m4v'"], returncode=1, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string into a vector of command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60082271/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.split()`; instead, specify your command directly as a list

```
scrape_cmd = ['ffprobe', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_streams', '-show_format',
              '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-hide_banner', file]
result = subprocess.run(scrape_cmd, capture_output=True)
print(result)
```

This is generally a good idea, because it avoids exactly the problem you ran into.

Comment: What if that string is an input? Instead, [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) should be used

Comment: I also see that the output, which is json is getting totaly messed up, the only thing that currently does no mess up to formatting is os.system

Comment: Shouldn't mess up the output... if you can't work it out, post a separate question?

Answer (score 0):

you can add quotes around the file in format string like this:"

```
scrape_cmd = ('ffprobe -print_format json -show_streams -show_format -loglevel quiet -hide_banner '
             f'"{file}"')
```

Comment: That won't stop `.split()` splitting up the filename, though?